# PHP from UTF-8 source to ASCII

Tags: php, csv, utf-8, ascii

I would like to create a CSV file from database data with PHP 5.6. My application and the database is using UTF-8, but the CSV needs to be in ASCII for windows with extended character set (eastern european languages).

I have already tried the following function but without success:

```
$data = utf8_decode($csv_data);
$data = mb_convert_encoding($csv_data, 'Windows-1252', 'UTF-8');
$data = mb_convert_encoding($csv_data, 'ASCII', 'UTF-8');
$data = mb_convert_encoding($csv_data, 'ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8');
$data = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1252", $csv_data);
$data = iconv("UTF-8", "CP437//TRANSLIT", $csv_data);

$data = htmlentities($csv_data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES , 'Windows-1252');

$data = htmlentities($csv_data, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$data = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_QUOTES , 'ISO-8859-15');
```

My problem is that I am unable to covert characters like this Ł (polish, L with stroke)

Comment: You can't convert to ASCII because `Ł` does not exist in ASCII. Have you tried `ISO-8859-1` or `ASCII//TRANSLIT`?

Comment: ASCII for windows with extended character set (eastern european languages)? Do you mean Windows-1251?

Comment: @Halcyon translit was not an options, I needed the exact same character. It seems to be fine with Windows-1250
@ÁlvaroGonzález Windows-1250 solved my problem`$data = iconv("UTF-8", "Windows-1250", $csv_data);`. Windows-1251 did not have polish characters.
Thanks!